# How to search a CSV column for a value in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, mysqli

I want to select those ids where staff id contain 3. Below is my database structure:

```
ID    NAME   Staff_ids
-----------------------
1     A       0,212,5
2     B       2,3,600
3     C       0,1,4
```

I want a query where I can select those ids having 3 in staff_ids column. How can I do that please help

Comment: What data type is Staff_ids?

Comment: data type is varchar

Comment: but I need exect record, coz using like will be confusing when staff id will contain 33 or something like value coz 33 is not same as 3

Comment: Why is your ID a string?

Comment: because that is an alphanumeric id

Comment: I agree with @Strawberry. Are you able to move the `Staff_ids` out into its own table? Storing multiple values per column usually makes things much slower, especially if you have to join.

Comment: You really should move the staff id's out to their own table.

Comment: Too broad.. OMG...WT...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `FIND_IN_SET`.

Here is [**SQLFiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/84547/1)

Input : [image]

Output: [image]

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE FIND_IN_SET('3',Staff_ids)>0
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM ABC
WHERE Staff_id IN ('3');
```

Check if this helps